# How can I add pure Angular app as project to Visual Studio solution?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I'd like to add Angular app with pure JavaScript/Less/Node files to Visual Studio solution as UI layer, but without creating even basic default infrastracture, that VS doing even for empty project. 
How Can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2017 and Angular 5 for me worked the next approach:

1. Add a new project: *HTML Application with TypeScript*
   [image: New 'HTML Application with TypeScript' project dialog]
2. Repeat almost the same steps from this nice 7min tutorial: [Angular 5 with ASP.NET MVC, Web API in Visual Studio 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHSTJBhJ44). The only difference is - copy the whole *index.html* file and remove unnecessary app.ts and app.css files.

Answer (score 35):

the easiest way to add an (existing) Angular Project, you can do the following:

1. Create a blank solution.
2. Open solution in VS2019
3. Right mouse click on the Solution
4. Click Add
5. Click existing website
6. Browse to the path of the existing angular project and select the folder.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It seems to me it's not possible to hide for instance node_modules folder, right?

Comment: @fabio-angela right click on it and select exclude from ...

Answer (score 3):

I created a Angular project outside the VS2019 by using the ng new command,
then I can add the angular proj into the VS2910 exsiting solution by
1. righ click the Solution from the VS2019, choose add existing Website, then select the folder which has all files and subfolder for this Angular prj,
Now you can see newly added Angular project as well as the existing other projs in the VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is considered part of setting up a project from an Angular folder!

Fabio if you find the node_modules folder in windows explorer, right click on it and then select 'properties'.  Then tick the 'hidden' property and say just for this folder so it doesn't iterate through the whole lot!
Then because it is hidden Visual Studio won't load it and searching will be magical again!
The folder is still there so this doesn't break any links, you just don't see it.